# Allow copy and paste in UITextView with character restrictions

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I would like to not allow the return button to be pressed on the keyboard while limiting the character count to 200.

**Problem:**

When I add restrictions to the UITextView, I cannot copy and paste into the textView.

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
   //character limit is set to 200
    let newText = (textView.text as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: text)
    let numberOfChars = newText.count
    if(numberOfChars > 200){
        return false
    }

    //remove return button keyboard functionality
   guard text.rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet.newlines) == nil else {
            return false
        }
    
    return true
}
```

**Desired Output:**

I would like to still have the ability to copy and paste into the textView while maintaining the two restrictions.

I would like the ability to disable the return key but still paste text with new lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it seems like you want to prevent the user from tapping the return key while typing but you want to allow pasted text with newlines, I would change the check from:

```
guard text.rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet.newlines) == nil else {
    return false
}
```

to just:

```
if text == "\n" {
    return false
}
```

That check prevents the entry of just a newline (pressing return). Technically it would also prevent a user from pasting a single newline but that's not something the user is going to do. It still allows pasting text that may also contain one or more newlines.